how to add or remove value from checkbox using interactive grid oracle apex
By checking the checkbox in the interactive grid, the value is being added to the page item, as I have highlighted in the image above.
But when I uncheck the checkbox, the value is not removed from the page item. Please, if there is a solution, kindly guide me.

You forgot to attach the image. I guess that there's some code behind what you explained which "adds value" to page item (or is supposed to "remove" it); consider posting that code as it is difficult to debug code you can't see. Once you do that, I hope someone will be able to assist.

Please document the full functionality you already have (preferably with text, not screenshots) - since someone might want to replicate your code trying to help you and that is a lot easier when the code can be copied from text
